# profile position mode + ros canopen

Tags: ros, ros-canopen

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I want to use profile postion mode with ros canopen, but i want the bits in the control word to be set in a certain way, for example:

Bit 5: If this bit is set to "1", a travel order triggered by bit 4 is immediately carried out. If it is set to
"0", the travel order just being carried out is completed and only then is the next travel order started.
Bit 6: If "0", the target position (607Ah) is absolute and if "1", the target position is relative to the
actual position. The reference position is depending on the Bits 0 and 1 of the object
60F2

How do i get ros canopen to set those bits in the control word so that the position value i am writing to the controller is interpreted correctly?

Is the DCF overlay configuration option in for the canopen_chain_mode the correct place to do this (i dont think it is..)?

I see line 232 in canopen_402/include/canopen_402/motor.h:
cw.set(CW_Immediate)

Would i replace this with cw.set(CW_Blending) to use the different setpoint options for profile position mode?

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/278209/profile-position-mode-+-ros-canopen/) by [JadTawil](https://answers.ros.org/users/29121/jadtawil/) on ROS Answers with karma: 71 on 2017-12-26

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The default implementation (absolute, immediate, no blending) made the most sense for generic use with `ros_control`.

If you want to change the PP mode behavior, you need to write your own `MotorBase` (e.g. subclass `Motor402`) plugin that registers a custom mode handler.

---

Originally posted by [Mathias Lüdtke](https://answers.ros.org/users/4094/mathias-l%C3%BCdtke/) with karma: 1596 on 2017-12-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0